# find combinations of values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
 id_x             id_y
  a                 b
  b                 c
  c                 d
  d                 a
  b                 a
and so on around (1000 rows)
```

i want to find the total  combinations for each id_x with id_y.
something like chaining

ie. a has combinations with `a-b,b-c,c-d`
similarly b has `combinations(b-c,c-d,d-a) and also a-b to be considered as a combination for b( a-b = b-a)`

and create a dataframe df2 which has

```
id   combinations  count
a          b,c,d     3
b          c,d,a     3
c          d,a,b     3
d          a,b,c     3
and so on ..(distinct product_id_'s)
```

and also if i could put each combinations in a different column in dataframe

```
id   c1  c2   c3...&so on   count
a     b   c   d               3              
b     c   d   a               3
```

what approach should i follow?
my skills on python are at a beginner level.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit about what you want to do.   Also, try writing some code to do it.

Comment: It is more complicated - I think you can add all output combination from input - it is a bit unclear what exactly need. Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael in short a chaining rule, `if a->b and b->c and c->d`
thus chains for a should have `a-> b,c,d`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
#generate dataframe    
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(id_x = ['a','b','c','d','b'], id_y = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']))

#generate second dataframe with swapped columns:
pdf_swapped = pdf.rename(columns = dict(id_x= 'id_y', id_y= 'id_x'))

#append both dataframes to each other
pdf_doubled = pd.concat([pdf, dummy_pdf])

#evaluate the frequency of each combination:
result = pdf_doubled.groupby('id_x').apply(lambda x: x.id_y.value_counts())
```

This gives the following result:

```
a     b    2
      d    1
b     a    2
      c    1
c     b    1
      d    1
d     c    1
      a    1
```

To figure out, how frequent the combination a-b is, you can simply do:

```
result['a', 'b']
```

Comment: @ for column `a` the combinations are `b and d` but i wanted `b,c and d`
since `a->b and b->c and c->d thus chains for a should have a-> b,c,d`

Comment: I see. How should loops like a->b, b->c, c->d , d->a be handled?